# Can no longer connect to localhost on mobile via computer's IP Address + port

Tags: testing, mobile, localhost, webserver

For months I have been connecting to my localhost on my [device] via computers.ip.address.x:port (both devices on exact same network), but I've noticed that each time I've tried over the last month, I can't ever get to the localhost. It's like I've accidentally messed with something on my macbook that is preventing this, as it doesn't work on any network.

This is now a huge issue as I can't do any mobile testing. Any help, ideas, etc., are much appreciated and I'll be on standby all day to fix this!

Thank you!

Oh, I do remember something that happened around the time it stopped working (I think it was around the time), is I began using a VPN, but I've been trying to connect to my localhost only OFF or DISCONNECTED to my VPN service, so I'm not sure if there is an issue with having used a VPN daily that's making this wonky.

Comment: I've turned on Remote Management and am visiting the URL of my computer w/ and w/o the port tagged along, but still not working.

Comment: I have installed ngrok, which is working really nicely, and I didn't realize I could send a client, for example, a URL to see my localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Use ngrok. That's how you do what I'm trying to do without wasting time worrying about whatever isn't working when something already works.